# Showing $A \subset C \wedge B \subset C \rightarrow A \cup B \subset C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am not sure if my justification is correct.

**Proposition:**

**$(A \subset C \wedge B  \subset C) \rightarrow A \cup B \subset C$**

In other words if A is subset B and B is subset of C then combined set AB is subset of C.

**My Proof**

X is any element.

$x \in A$ then $x \in C$ because C contains A. If $x \in B \rightarrow x \in C$ because C contains A.

Assume A and B are combined and now share all their elements. $x\in A \lor x \in B$

This new set is now K.

K however is subset of C since component A and B are subset of B.

Comment: yes you are right I am not sure how to make the U shape in latex

Comment: the code for union is \cup and for intersection \cap

Comment: ok I shall I edit it

Comment: Your proof looks ok, but a bit lenghty. A simpler version might be: Let $x\in A\cup B$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, by definition. In both cases, $x$ is in $C$ by assumption. Finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in A \cup B$. We want to show that $x \in C$. Since $x$ is in the union of $A$ and $B$, $x\in A$ or $x \in B$.
If $x \in A$, then $x\in C$ since $A\subset C$. If $x\not\in A$, it must be true that $x\in B$. It follows that $x\in C$ since $B\subset C$.

Comment: Can I go from $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ to $x\in C$ or $x\in C$ by using the hypothesis?

Answer (score 1):

Using words we get every element of $A$ is in $C$ and every element of $B$ is in $C$. Now we can conclude if an element is in $A$ or in $B$ then it is in $C$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\cup B\not\subset C$, then there exists an $x\in A\cup B$ such that $x\notin C$. It follows that $A\not\subset C$ or $B\not\subset C$.